Interactive facet plot with ggiraph: not responding to mouse-over
My aim is to generate an interactive combined line plot and facet dot plot in R. Moving the mouse over one of the lines should highlight it together with the corresponding dot plot facet, and vice versa. I have been trying to follow Albert Rapp's approach using ggiraph together with patchwork.
However, at the moment I am stuck at generating the interactive facet plot. Here is an example for the code which produces an unresponsive facet plot:
library(ggirafe) 
library(ggplot2) 

# Sample data 
data <- 
    data.frame( 
        x = rnorm(100), 
        y = rnorm(100), 
        facet = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 
        length.out = 100) 
        ) 

# Create the ggplot 
p <- 
    ggplot(
        data, aes(x, y), 
        data_id = facet
        ) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap_interactive(~facet)

# Create the girafe object with hover options 
girafe(
    ggobj = p, 
    options = 
        list( opts_hover(css = ""), 
        opts_hover_inv(css = "opacity:0.1;") 
        )
    )

Thanks for any suggestions!

From my understanding and a look at the ggiraph book making the facet strips interactive requires using labeller_interactive to set the data_id.
library(ggiraph)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

# Sample data
data <-
  data.frame(
    x = rnorm(100),
    y = rnorm(100),
    facet = rep(c("A", "B", "C"),
      length.out = 100
    )
  )

p <-
  ggplot(
    data, aes(x, y)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap_interactive(
    ~facet,
    labeller = labeller_interactive(
      aes(
        tooltip = paste("this is facet", facet), 
        data_id = facet
      )
    )
  )

girafe(
  ggobj = p,
  options =
    list(
      opts_hover(""),
      opts_hover_inv(css = "opacity:0.1;")
    )
)



Thank you stefan.  Actually, I tried this before, but also copied and pasted your code. However, the facets are still non-responsive in R Studio or when saved as an html doc.
Also, the desired response in the example image would  have been a reduction in opacity for all of panels A and B (not just the label), and no tooltip.  By contrast, I have no problems generating the interactive line plot described in my question above.  I am using a Windows PC, R Studio 2024.04.1 and ggiraph 0.8.10.

Hm. I'm running on a Mac with the latest version of RStudio. But I just checked on a Windows machine with R 4.3, RStudio 2024.09.0, ggiraph 0.8.10 and works fine too. Concerning the other questions. The tooltip= was just for illustrative purposes. You can simply drop it. And one option to apply the css to the strip background too would be to add interactive_on = "both" to facet_wrap_interactive.

Hi stefan, this is very odd. I updated RStudio, and also ran your code online in the posit Cloud. However, the plots are completely unresponsive in both cases. As I wrote, interactive line plots are fine!

Hm. I also checked on Posit cloud and the code works fine there too: https://i.sstatic.net/kZAuoF3b.png

Thanks for your help! Here is a slightly modified code that produces the kind of figure I wanted:
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point_interactive(aes(data_id = facet)) +
  facet_wrap_interactive(
    ~facet,
    interactive_on = "both",
    labeller = labeller_interactive(aes(data_id = facet))
  ) +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12)
  )

girafe(
  ggobj = p,
  options = list(
    opts_hover(""),
    opts_hover_inv(css = "opacity:0.1;")
  )
)

I think the problems were 1. mouse-over needs to be rather precisely on the text in the facet strip - here a single letter, 2. in the original code, data_id = facet was part of the global aestethics, but it seems it needs to be placed inside labeller_interactive to make the facets interactive
enter image description here
